# How can I easily copy tables from Microsoft Word document to Quarto in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to copy tables from Microsoft Word to Quarto. For example, consider the simple table, which I have got in Microsoft Word. When I copy it from Microsoft Word to Quarto, I get many extra characters in the output.

| YAML Variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| title | The title of the document |
| author | The author of the document |
| date | Date of last modification |

I have also attempted to convert the word document to Markdown, and then pasting the markdown content into Quarto. But when I do this, and click on "Render" button, the output contains the markdown code, not the formatted table. So, how can I copy such tables from Microsoft Word and preserve the formatting in Quarto?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by first pasting the tables in Microsoft Excel, and then importing the tables using readxl package.